# Change a pending transaction's "Gas Limit" & "GWEI"

Tags: gas, metamask, gas-limit

a noob question here!
I'm using Metamask, I've sent a transaction to another wallet. I would like to **increase** the Gas Limit and **reduce** the gas price. Is this possible? If so, how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can increase the gas limit and the gas price too can be set by you.Each operation in a contract requires some amount of gas which will be used from the quantity you specify.So if this quantity*gas price(set by you) suffices the need then yeah your trasaction will be processed.
I have found a useful post here regarding gas limits and prices.Check it out over here

https://steemit.com/ethereum/@tomshwom/ethereum-gas-how-it-works